# Execute both JavaScript function and managed bean action with one button click

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Is it possible to execute a JavaScript action like `bar.show()` of PrimeFaces notification bar and a managed bean action like `#{managedBean.foo}` with one button click of a JSF component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check vdl of primefaces commandButton: http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/commandButton.html

use action or actionListener for bean and for example onclick for clientside javascript callback

edit (added example):

```
<h:form id="formId">
    <p:commandButton value="Button" update="formId" id="ajax"  
         actionListener="#{myBean.serverSideBeanMethod}" onclick="clientSideJavaScriptFunction()" />
</h:form>
```